# How to annotate pdf file in Angular 2

Tags: angular, pdf

I am new to Angular.

Currently, I have a application that renders pdf file.

I want to annotate/make changes on the pdf file.  Like adding drawings: circle, lines or even text.

How can I do that in Angular 2?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I used pdf-extended-viewer. But, still not sure how to annotate it. Can you share if you solved it already?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `pdf-annotate.js` plugin that works on `pdf.js`. It can be used to create the following annotations.

- Area
- Drawing
- Highlight
- Point
- Strikeout
- Textbox

For examples, follow the links in https://github.com/instructure/pdf-annotate.js/tree/master/docs.

If you need more examples, you can refer to the tests that are available in the `render` folder. Following is an example to render a line.

```
import renderLine from '../../src/render/renderLine';

let line = renderLine({
      rectangles: [
        {
          x: 25,
          y: 50,
          width: 100
        }
      ]
    });
```

Comment: For future visitors, pdf-annotate is no longer being maintained and has been archived by the owner

Answer (score 0):

Adobe's pdf-embed Javascript API can be used to do this. It is free to use.

https://www.adobe.io/apis/documentcloud/dcsdk/pdf-embed.html

Check out the demo at

https://documentcloud.adobe.com/view-sdk-demo/index.html#/view/FULL_WINDOW/Bodea%20Brochure.pdf

It supports text comments, sticky notes, highlighting, and drawing. There is a save callback to save the changes to your own storage.